# Laravel and DOMPDF images do not load when generating PDF

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-blade, dompdf

I am trying to generate a PDF file using DOMPDF in a Laravel project.
The image is displayed correctly when generating my Blade template. On the other hand, the image is not displayed in the generation of the PDF file (the PDF file uses the Blade template).

The controller

```
 $pdf = domPDF::loadView($blade, compact('cv', 'user', 'cv_certifications', 'cv_skills_nom', 'experiences', 'formations','perso', 'adresse', 'region', 'region_select', 'cv_skills', 'tcontrat'));

// Viewing the PDF file in the browser viewer
return $pdf->stream(); // display
```

The template

```
<img src="{{URL::asset($perso[0]->cvp_photo_path)}}" height="auto" width="150">
```

**What I want**

I would like the image to display in the Generated PDF file

**What I get**

I obit no errors in the server logs nor in laravel. The image does not load into the PDF file but loads into the rendered template correctly.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `src="{{asset(Storage::url($perso[0]->cvp_photo_path))}}"` and then 
`return $pdf->download('download.pdf');`
try this

Comment: Merci pour votre commentaire.
J'ai déjà essayer ceci, le lien reste le même. Et le fait de télécharger ou d'afficher le fichier ne change rien non plus à mon problème.

Comment: if possible can you tell about the size and type of file extension of pdf, also please speak english

Comment: Oh sorry.
I am trying to include JPG or PNG type images with size less than 2MB.

I put my old comment back:
Thank you for your comment. I have already tried this, the link remains the same. And downloading or viewing the file doesn't change my problem either.